# Error related to Android SDK ANT build file while building for Android in Ionic framework

Tags: android, ant, ionic-framework

while building for android, I have an error related to ant build file in android sdk\tools. The error is:

> C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734:
>   Unable to find a javac compiler; com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on
>   the classpath. Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. It is
>   currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25"

I am using Java SDK 1.6 in JAVA_HOME. I am not sure from where it is picking this JAVA_HOME path. The following environment variables are set correctly:

1. JAVA_HOME to 1.6.
2. ANDROID_HOME
3. ANT_HOME

All paths are referenced. But, still getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and none of the other answers worked.

Originally when I would run the following build command

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

It would output the path to the JDK with the **/bin** folder appended to the end, so I tried removing this and then resetting the environment variable and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25"

The path `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25` seems to refer to a *JRE*, not a JDK and this is why the compiler is missing. The JDK home would be something similar to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why Ionic does this but the steps I used to fix this were the following:

First check the path `%JAVA_HOME%` is set to:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

Mine came up with the proper response but Ionic was still having trouble  compiling the whole ordeal.

Then I:

1. `SET JAVA_HOME= [put the path to JDK such as C:\java\jdk8]`
2. Went back into environment variables and added the path again for the specific version of JDK I was using.

Here is a [link](http://roboticsforyou.blogspot.com/2010/04/setting-java-home-through-command-line.html) that provides more details.